# Error: Invalid use of void pointer

Tags: c

Reading about void pointers:-

3. When we assign address of integer to the void pointer, pointer will become Integer Pointer.
4. When we assign address of Character Data type to void pointer it will become Character Pointer.

And the code:

```
  void main()
  {
  float f = 111.35;
  void * fp;
  fp = &f;
  printf("%.2f\n",*fp);
  }
```

It shows the error follows :Invalid use of void pointer
If I change the type of the pointer to a float * fp, there is no error.

Answer (score 3):

The type of a `void` pointer is "pointer to `void`" and nothing else. And since `void` doesn't have a type you have to explicit cast it to the correct type when dereferencing it, like

```
*(float *) fp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable type must be specified before printf or in the printf, thus you can not access a void * variable before you cast it to a right type of c.

Answer (score 0):

```
The prime benefit of using void pointer is its reusability.
You can use fp to point to a char* or int* or float* in successive statements.
When you state vp =&f, it implies that vp can act as a float pointer.
It does not become a float pointer.
So when you dereference it ( as in printf), you need to typecast it.

int main()
{
int iVal = 9;
float fVal = 9.0;
void *ptr;

ptr = &iVal; 
printf("iVal = %d\n",*((int*)ptr)); //De-referencing

//Resuability
ptr = &fVal;  
printf("fVal = %f\n",*((float*)ptr)); //De-referencing

return(0);
}
```